# How to use Checkbox from material-UI to toggle strikethrough on a todo list item

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, redux-saga, immutable.js

```
const Todo: React.FC<ITodoProps> = (props) => {
const [textInput, setTextInput] = useState('');

const {
 addTodo,
 userId,
 todosForUser,
 user,
} = props;
if (user == null) {
 return (
  <Grid
    container={true}
    direction='column'
    wrap='nowrap'
  >
    <Grid
      item={true}
    >
      <Typography
        variant='h5'
      >
        INVALID USER
      </Typography>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
);
}
return (
 <Grid
  container={true}
  direction='column'
  wrap='nowrap'
 >
  <Grid
    item={true}
  >
    <Typography
      variant='h5'
    >
      TODOS FOR {user.get('name')}
    </Typography>
  </Grid>
  <Grid
    container={true}
    item={true}
    direction='column'
    wrap='nowrap'
  >
    <Grid
      item={true}
      container={true}
      alignItems='center'
    >
      <Grid
        item={true}
      >
        <TextField
          label='title'
          value={textInput}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setTextInput(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
      </Grid>
      <Grid
        item={true}
      >
        <Button
          variant='outlined'
          onClick={
            () => {
              addTodo(
                userId,
                TodoFactory({
                  title: textInput,
                }),
              );
              setTextInput('');
            }
          }
        >
          Add Todo
        </Button>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
    {
      todosForUser.map((todo, index) => {
        return <Grid
          key={index}
          item={true}
        >
```

Here is the Checkbox

```
        <Checkbox>

        </Checkbox>
```

Here is the target todo list

```
          {todo.get('title')}




        </Grid>;
      })
    }
  </Grid>
</Grid>
);
}
```

I'm using material-UI, typescript, react, redux, saga, immutablejs.

Basically, it's a todo list and I'm struggling with how to do a line-through on a list item when the  is toggled.

Here is how it looks 
[When checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6cQw.png)
[When unchecked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8kyt.png)

I couldn't get my head around how to use Checkbox with onClick with this stack. Help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When I was trying to mark items as deleted (a strikethrough effect) I used the `<del>` tag in my list.

Example:

```
<ListItem key={"occasion-list-item-" + occasion.Id} button onClick={() => handleToggle(occasion)}>
  { occasion.Enabled ? 
    (
      <ListItemText id={occasion.Id} primary={JSON.stringify(occasion.Enabled)} />
    )
    :
    (
      <del>
      <ListItemText id={occasion.Id} primary={JSON.stringify(occasion.Enabled)} />
      </del>
    )
  }
</ListItem>
```

Where occasion is a POJO like:

```
{
  "Id" : <some sort of string guid>,
  "Enabled" : true
}
```

You'd have a handler which would go and update the value `Enabled` in that item in your component state and then react will re-render your page. When it re-renders the page, `Enabled` is `true` so chooses the first code path.